# Can't get a good overlapping with RelativeLayout

Tags: android, overlapping, android-relativelayout

I would like to do a presentation like this : (done with `Gimp`)
[image: Good part is with 03 sept.]

And for the moment I only get something like this :
[image: Bad result]

My layout xml file is for the moment like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/itemRoot"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="4sp"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bigbox"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="20px"
android:background="#caced4"
android:clipChildren="false"
android:onClick="itemClicked">
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/box"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10px"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
        <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
        android:layout_width="40dip" 
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:background="@drawable/corner"
        >
        <TextView android:text="03 sept."
        android:background="#424e5f" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3px"
        android:layout_marginRight="3px"
        android:layout_marginTop="3px"
        android:id="@+id/itemPubdate" 
        android:gravity="center" android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="4sp">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
        android:text="Arrêtez moi ces répondeurs d'email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textColor="#424e5f"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/itemDescription"
        android:text="Qui, suite à l'envoi d'un email, n'a pas reçu etc."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:textSize="11sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried many combinaisons with `android:clipChildren="false"` without any good result .. If someone have a solution for this ... that will help me so much.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you need the same layout as on first image?

Comment: please see my answer for a quick and an other, efficient solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try a simplified layout, like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/itemRoot" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingBottom="4sp">
    <LinearLayout android:paddingLeft="45dip" android:background="#caced4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:clipChildren="false" android:onClick="itemClicked">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
            android:text="Arrêtez moi ces répondeurs d'email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:maxLines="2" android:textColor="#424e5f" android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/itemDescription"
            android:text="Qui, suite à l'envoi d'un email, n'a pas reçu etc."
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textColor="#000000" android:maxLines="3" android:textSize="11sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" android:background="@drawable/corner"
        android:layout_width="40dip" android:layout_height="40dip">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/itemPubdate" android:text="03 sept."
            android:background="#424e5f" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3px" android:layout_marginBottom="3px"
            android:layout_marginRight="3px" android:layout_marginTop="3px"
            android:gravity="center" android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

or thinking a bit more about it, take the full advantage of the `RelativeLayout`. 
That would contain only your calendar-item (`TableLayout`), and the two `TextViews`, but for this you'd probably need a custom drawable (a simple solid-colored one with an `android:top="10dp"` set.

**Update**:
With `RelativeLayout` and two custom drawables (from which one you already partially have: `corner`), you can achieve this layout:

[image: overlapping layout sample]

For such a result you need the 
**row_layout.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/itemRoot" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="4sp"
    android:background="@drawable/overlap" android:onClick="itemClicked">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/itemPubdate" android:text="03 sept."
        android:background="@drawable/overlap_calendar" 
        android:layout_width="40dip" android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:gravity="center" android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/itemTitle" android:paddingLeft="5sp"
        android:text="Arrêtez moi ces répondeurs d'email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:maxLines="2" android:textColor="#424e5f" android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/itemPubdate" android:paddingTop="10dp"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/itemDescription" android:paddingLeft="5sp"
        android:text="Qui, suite à l'envoi d'un email, n'a pas reçu etc."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="#000000" android:maxLines="3" android:textSize="11sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/itemPubdate"
        android:layout_below="@id/itemTitle" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the two referenced drawables
**res/drawable/overlap.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="10dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp" 
        android:right="2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#caced4" />
            <stroke android:width="3dp" color="#caced4" />
            <padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp"
                android:bottom="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and **res/drawable/overlap_calendar.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#f0f0f0" />
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp" android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
                android:topRightRadius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="2dp" android:left="2dp" android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#424e5f" />
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp" android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
                android:topRightRadius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/itemRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="4sp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    >
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="#caced4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bigbox"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bigbox"
        ></View>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/box"
        >
            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="40dip"
                android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
                android:background="@drawable/corner"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
            >
                <TextView
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="03 sept."
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3px"
                    android:id="@+id/itemPubdate"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3px"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3px"
                    android:background="#424e5f"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3px"
                ></TextView>
            </TableLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bigbox"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20px"
            android:onClick="itemClicked"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/box"
        >
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="4sp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
            >
                <TextView
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:text="Arrêtez moi ces répondeurs d'email"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#424e5f"
                    android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                ></TextView>
                <TextView
                    android:maxLines="3"
                    android:text="Qui, suite à l'envoi d'un email, n'a pas reçu etc."
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:id="@+id/itemDescription"
                    android:textSize="11sp"
                ></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks also ,but @rekaszeru solution seems to be cleaner for me!